# VBA to extract Source Code text

Tags: vba, excel, web-scraping

I would like to send the value **$871.63** to my spreadsheet, from the following HTML extract:

```
<tr>
   <th>Insurer</th>
   <th>12-month Price</th>
   <th>6-month Price</th>
   <th class="print-hide-th">Price Breakdown</th>
   <th>Phone</th>
   <th>Web Site</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
   <tr>
      <td>AAMI</td>
      <td><span id="MainPlaceHolder_lblAAMIFull">$871.63</span></td>
      <td><span id="MainPlaceHolder_lblAAMIHalf">$447.12</span></td>
      <td class="print-hide-td"><a href="PriceBreakDown.aspx?companyName=AAMI&policyCost=$871.63&region=Metro&class=1&startDate=2/01/2016" class="info">more information</a></td>
      <td class="no-wrap">132 244</td>
```

I've tried

```
Cells(1, 1) = IE.Document.getElementByID("MainPlaceHolder_lblAAMIFull").outerText
```

But that doesn't work - can you suggest a solution?

Here is the entire code that I've trying and which works until that last line:

```
Sub GetQuotes()

On Error Resume Next

Dim IE As Object

Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

IE.navigate ("http://prices.maa.nsw.gov.au/")

IE.Visible = True

Do
DoEvents
Loop Until IE.readystate = 4

'STEP 1

IE.Document.getElementByID("Q1a_Day").SelectedIndex = 1
IE.Document.getElementByID("Q1b_Month").SelectedIndex = 1
IE.Document.getElementByID("Q1c_Year").SelectedIndex = 1

IE.Document.getElementByID("btnNext").Click


'STEP 2

IE.Document.getElementByID("Q2a_VehicleClass").SelectedIndex = 1

'YOU OFTEN NEED THE WEBPAGE TO UPDATE BEFORE YOU CAN MANIPULATE OTHER FIELDS - SEE dispatchEvent lines

Set evt = IE.Document.createEvent("HTMLEvents")
evt.initEvent "change", True, False
Set lst = IE.Document.getElementByID("Q3_VehicleYear")
lst.Value = 2015
lst.dispatchEvent evt


IE.Document.getElementByID("Q3b_VehicleMake").SelectedIndex = 2
IE.Document.getElementByID("Q3b_VehicleMake").dispatchEvent evt


IE.Document.getElementByID("Q3c_VehicleModel").SelectedIndex = 1
IE.Document.getElementByID("Q3c_VehicleModel").dispatchEvent evt


IE.Document.getElementByID("Q4_Postcode").Value = 2000
IE.Document.getElementByID("Q4_Postcode").dispatchEvent evt

IE.Document.getElementByID("Q5_CompanyOwned").SelectedIndex = 2

IE.Document.getElementByID("Q6_Usage").SelectedIndex = 2

IE.Document.getElementByID("Q7_CurrentCTP").Value = "N"

IE.Document.getElementByID("btnNext").Click


'STEP 3

IE.Document.getElementByID("Q7_CurrentCTP").SelectedIndex = 1
IE.Document.getElementByID("Q7_CurrentCTP").dispatchEvent evt

IE.Document.getElementByID("Q8_CurrentCTPCompany").SelectedIndex = 1

IE.Document.getElementByID("Q10_OtherInsurance").SelectedIndex = 1
IE.Document.getElementByID("Q10_OtherInsurance").dispatchEvent evt

IE.Document.getElementByID("Q11_OtherInsuranceCompany").SelectedIndex = 1
IE.Document.getElementByID("Q11_OtherInsuranceCompany").dispatchEvent evt

IE.Document.getElementByID("Q12_OtherInsuranceYears").SelectedIndex = 1

IE.Document.getElementByID("Q13a_NoClaimDiscount").SelectedIndex = 1

IE.Document.getElementByID("btnNext").Click


'STEP 4

IE.Document.getElementByID("Q14_OwnerAge").Value = 25
IE.Document.getElementByID("Q14_OwnerAge").dispatchEvent evt

IE.Document.getElementByID("Q15_Demerits").SelectedIndex = 1

IE.Document.getElementByID("Q16_DriverAge").Value = 23
IE.Document.getElementByID("Q16_DriverAge").dispatchEvent evt


IE.Document.getElementByID("Q17_Accidents2yr").SelectedIndex = 1
IE.Document.getElementByID("Q17_Accidents2yr").dispatchEvent evt

IE.Document.getElementByID("Q19_Convictions").SelectedIndex = 1
IE.Document.getElementByID("Q19_Convictions").dispatchEvent evt

IE.Document.getElementByID("Q17b_YearsDriverWLic").SelectedIndex = 1
IE.Document.getElementByID("Q17b_YearsDriverWLic").dispatchEvent evt

IE.Document.getElementByID("NRMARadioYes").Click

IE.Document.getElementByID("Q18_Roadside").SelectedIndex = 3
IE.Document.getElementByID("Q18_Roadside").dispatchEvent evt

IE.Document.getElementByID("btnNext").Click


'STEP 5

IE.Document.getElementByID("btnSubmit").Click

'GET PRICES

Cells(1, 1) = IE.Document.getElementByID("MainPlaceHolder_lblAAMIFull").innerText 



End Sub
```

I'd be really grateful for a solution!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't an `outerText` property.  There is an `innerHTML` and an `outerHTML` but I think that you are looking for the `innerText` property.

```
Cells(1, 1) = IE.Document.getElementByID(&quot;MainPlaceHolder_lblAAMIFull&quot;).innerText
```

**Update:**  J Ried was right about the page not loading.  The `On Error Resume Next` was preventing you from catching the error.  The problem was that after click the submit button it takes time for the page to update.  You were trying to find an element that wasn't loaded yet.  I added a 4 second delay and the code executed properly.

At the top of the module:

---

```
#If VBA7 Then
    Public Declare PtrSafe Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As LongPtr) 'For 64 Bit Systems
#Else
    Public Declare Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long) 'For 32 Bit Systems
#End If
```

### Add a 4 second delay after you click the submit button.

```
'STEP 5

IE.document.getElementById("btnSubmit").Click

Sleep 4000
```

Comment: Thanks for the response - changed it to that and it still doesn't work. Also tried outerHTML and innerHTML to see if it did anything but it's not. Is there some other way you would be inclined to use to extract a string like that?

Comment: Is it throwing an error?  If so, what error?  Or is it returning the wrong value.

Comment: It doesn't do anything - doesn't throw an error and the cell is just blank

Comment: Can you post your code?  What you should do is set a variable to the element and add a watch to the variable or check the variable in the Locals Window.

Comment: Could be the page hasn't finished loading ... might need a `IE.ReadyState`  I forget the rest before Cells(1, 1)

Comment: @JReid If the page didn't finish loading; it would throw an `Object variable or With block variable not set
` error.

Comment: @ThomasInzina you are more than likely correct! All I know is the code you posted works for me too

Comment: @JReid  You were right.  `On Error Resume Next` strikes again!

Comment: Thanks for the solution - may I ask what the code that you've put at the top of the module is for? I also ask because I managed to send the value I need to send, without actually using that code

Comment: [Sleep](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686298(v=vs.85).aspx) is an API call to a function inside a DLL file.  It allows you to suspend the execution of a thread for a period of time.  It is more efficient that `DoEvents`.  The hash marks `#` indicate compiler directives.  It tells the compiler which version of the function to use base on VBA's version being 32bit or 64bit.